# How to debug StackOverflow Exceptions

Tags: c#, iis, exception, stack-overflow

I want to filter my database entries with a `custom filter panel`. Some of my filter fields are `multiselectable comboboxes`. When I select too many filters, my IIS throws a `stackoverflow exception`. I have absolutely no idea how to debug this. Even if I attach the w3wp.exe to my process I have no meaningful report.

Is there any way to debug this kind of exception?

Comment: StackOverflow exception usually means that there is too many functions calls. It's the case when doing recursion wrong. You can get some ideas by looking at your exception **stack** trace, there you should notice why your call stack is getting big. P.S. with debugger attached you should be also to see this error in debugger and you can see stack trace there if you are not doing any exception logging.

Comment: You have a recursive problem in your code somewhere - a function that is called in an endless loop. Are you using some kind of tree-structure in your list where a child-node references a parent-node as a child-node somewhere?

Comment: The IIS throws the exception directly after the incoming request. How is that possible?

Comment: Attach the debugger *before* it blows up.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea WHERE before is.. The request sends succesfully and when the request arrives the IIS throws the exception.. I have no idea how to spot the failure..

Comment: Wild guess: a property gone wrong? such as `public string MyValue { set { MyValue = value; } }` - this will blow up (note that this doesn't set the backing variable but the property itself)

Comment: Probably a good idea, but when I deselect some filters there is no StackOverflow Exception.. So I guess it's not a setter.. I searched for the error for 2 days but without any success..

Comment: Ah, but then you have narrowed it down to those filters! Try to narrow it down to one filter and investigate that. Maybe post its code and how you attach it here?

Comment: The code for the filters is about a few thousand lines. But why I don't get any javascript error? The Frontend is written in ExtJS 4.

Comment: Do you have some events set to your filters? Like `Checked`? I can't recall how it looked like exactly, but I know I managed to get a SO Exception using events before...

Comment: I use the select event and the blur event..

Comment: And do either of those events do anything that might cause the events to be fired again?

Comment: I would say no..